# Magento 1.9.2.2 upgrade to 1.9.2.4 fails via Connect Manager

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, ce-1.9.2.2

I am trying to upgrade all packages via Magento Connect Manager but keep getting the following:

```
Checking dependencies of packages

CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.2
Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.2.2, community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.2.2, community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default 1.9.2.2, community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.2.2, community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.2.2, community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.2.2, community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.2.2, community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.2.2, community/Magento_Mobile 1.9.2.2, community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.5 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.2.2, community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_Magento 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_Credis 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.2.2, community/Lib_Cm 1.9.2.2, community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_ZF 1.12.10.4 conflicts with: community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.2.4 conflicts with: community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.2.2, community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.2
Package community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.4 conflicts with: community/Lib_ZF 1.12.10.2
```

I have deleted /pkginfo/Mage_All_latest.txt as per other suggestions I found, but nothing changes. How I can I fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Delete **pkginfo/Mage_All_latest.txt** and then from magento connect try to upgrade only **mage_all_latest** only.. It will upgrade everything successfully without any issues.

I did same and it worked.

Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Hi, tried this, but ended with partially deleted magento files. I had backup so I rolled back, but I'm not sure what was the reason for this deletion.

Comment: The path of pkginfo is ~..... public_html/pkginfo/Mage_All_latest.txt

Answer (score 3):

I deleted `pkginfo/Mage_All_latest.txt` and then from Magento Connect, upgraded `Mage_All_Latest` to `1.9.2.4` and it upgraded everything successfully without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

In my case there were files that couldn't be replaced because they were considered folders instead of files. Check the errors from the upgrade, as they are giving you instructions on what to delete:
upgrade-all: Failed to delete files:

> public_html/./app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect//edit/tab/design/preview/banner_rotator.phtml
>
> public_html/./app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect//edit/tab/design/preview/catalog_android.phtml

and this is why the upgrade fails.
Connect ftp to your server and delete them.
Remove them and give again the uprade command: `./mage upgrade-all --force`