# Can't complete upgrade to 1.9.3.7 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

We have Magento CE 1.9.3.4.

Using Magento Connect, I see we have updates available (up to 1.9.3.7).

When I first started upgrading, I got a whole lot of lines like:

> Package community/Lib_Varien 1.9.2.7 conflicts with:
>   community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.2.4

I read [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108157/18513), which suggests deleting `/pkginfo/Mage_All_latest.txt`.

I did this, and now the upgrade commences, but the console window keeps repeating the text:

```
Checking dependencies of packages

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages

Cleaning cache
..............
```

I refreshed the page, and tried the upgrade again, and now receive:

```
Checking dependencies of packages
Already installed: community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Downloader 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Magento_Mobile 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Cm 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Cm_RedisSession 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Core_Adminhtml 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.13, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Js_TinyMCE 3.5.11.12, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Varien 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.13, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Mage 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Magento 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Credis 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_ZF 1.12.10.12, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.9.3.7, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.10.12, skipping

Cleaning cache

Checking dependencies of packages
..............
```

and this last crop of messages just repeats in a circle.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try upgrading Mage_All_Latest only, instead of full upgrade?

Comment: HI @RickyOdinMatthews I don't understand how to do that. Can you help me understand?

Comment: are you using Magento connect or the commandline?

Comment: Magneo Connect, @RickyOdinMatthews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find in your Magento root directory 'pkginfo' folder and delete inside of this folder Mage_All_Latest.txt. After this go to the Magento Connect Manager, click on the 'Check for Updates' button. After this find among the all modules in the list 'Mage_All_Latest' and choose in its dropdown 'Upgrade to 1.9.3.7 (stable)'. In the end push 'Commit Changes' button.

Comment: I've tried this Vladishev. Please re-read the question. :-)

Comment: Try to remove all the files from var/package/ folder (just cut it and paste to some temporary folder) - it contains information about your current modules (e.g. Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default-1.9.3.6.xml). Also clean the downloader/.cache folder - just in case.

Comment: When I moved the contents of `/var/package/` to `/var/package(temp)`, and click "Check for Updates" in Magento Connect, my only options for each module became `Reinstall / Uninstall`. If I move the contents of `/var/package(temp)` back to `/var/package` the issue remains.

Comment: Hi Vlad. Although the only options are `Reinstall / Uninstall`, I notice the version of modules are 1.9.3.7, which is the latest version, so I think you've fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Mage_All_Latest, then upgraded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily upgrade to the latest version of Magento 1.x by running the following commands one by one from your Shell/Command Prompt

```
./mage mage-setup .
./mage sync
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

Comment: I tried this, but `mage-setup` & `./mage` were not found. I downloaded a copy of Magento 1.9.3.7 but there was no `mage` folder in this either.

Comment: @Steve mage is not a directory. It is an executable file located in the root directory of your Magento instance.